# Passing userID into booking table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user table that links to a booking table so I can tell what users have made what bookings.  I have tried to left join the user table with the booking table but it didn't work.  I also experimented with trying to pass the session userID but again it didn't work.  My PHP code is presented below that I'm trying to pass through at the minute.

```html
 <?php
  include "config.php"; 
  
  //Booking point
  if(isset($_POST['booking']))
  {
   //get values for variables
   $pitchID = $_POST['pitchID'];
   $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
   $start_hour = $_POST['start_hour'];
   $end_hour = $_POST['end_hour'];
   $booking_age = $_POST['booking_age'];
   $pitch_size = $_POST['pitch_size'];
   $light_tokens = $_POST['light_tokens'];
   
   $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * 
         FROM booking  
         LEFT JOIN user 
         ON booking.userID=user.userID");
   $query = $q-> execute();
   
    if($query)
    {
     $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO booking SET pitchID = ?, start_date = ?, start_hour = ?, end_hour = ?, booking_age = ?, pitch_size = ?, light_tokens = ?");
     $query = $q->execute(array($pitchID,$start_date,$start_hour,$end_hour,$booking_age,$pitch_size,$light_tokens));
     $count = $q->rowCount();
     
     if($count == 1){
      echo "Your booking has been made";
      header("Location:home2_template.html");
      return; 
     }else {
      echo "Fail";
     }
    } else {
     echo"Booking already exists";
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: echo `sql query` and run it in `phpmyadmin` and check what's wrong with it

Comment: I ran the SELECT statement and it returns all my bookings but there is no userID associated with them.  When I log in as a user should that ID not pass through to anything that is linked with it i.e. my booking table

Comment: if you are logged in as a user than you can get it by taking `user's id` in `session`

Comment: Thanks Vicky.  I had to set up the session variable in the login section of my system and pass it through from there.  Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I added the session variable in the login section of my system then passed it through from there.

Login section below:

```html
<?php
 include "config.php"; 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $username = $_POST['username']; 
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 
 $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
 $query = $q->execute(array($username, $password));
 while($dbRow = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $userID = $dbRow['userID'];
 }
 $count = $q->rowCount();
 if($count == 1){
  session_start(); 
  $_SESSION['userID'] = $userID; 
  header("Location:home2_template.html"); 
  return;
 }else{
  echo "You have entered an incorrect login/password";
  }
 }
?>
```

I also removed the join in the PHP code and ended up with this below.  It passed through my userID but there are still bugs in this code for anyone who is viewing this.  I had to declare the variable userID at the top of my page then again in my prepare statement.

```html
<?php 
session_start(); 
 $userID = $_SESSION['userID']; 
?>
```

```html
<?php
  include "config.php"; 
  echo $userID; 
  //Booking point
  if(isset($_POST['booking']))
  {
   //get values for variables
   $pitchID = $_POST['pitchID'];
   $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
   $start_hour = $_POST['start_hour'];
   $end_hour = $_POST['end_hour'];
   $booking_age = $_POST['booking_age'];
   $pitch_size = $_POST['pitch_size'];
   $light_tokens = $_POST['light_tokens'];
   
   $q = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO booking SET pitchID = ?, start_date = ?, start_hour = ?, end_hour = ?, booking_age = ?, pitch_size = ?, light_tokens = ?, userID='$userID'");
   $query = $q->execute(array($pitchID,$start_date,$start_hour,$end_hour,$booking_age,$pitch_size,$light_tokens));
   
   $count = $q->rowCount();
    if($count == 0)
    {
     echo "Your booking has been made";
     header("Location:home2_template.html");
     return; 
    }else {
     echo "That booking already exists";
    }
  }
 
 ?>
```